# Why do I keep receiving a non type error when saving input value from html form in python?

Tags: python, forms, cgi, html

I'm creating an online store that displays an item and under it there's space for the user to input the quantity they want of this item.

This is how it looks like in code:

HTML PAGE(example of an item):

```html
<form>
All the information in the page
<The image of the item displayed here>
<label for="tanks">Desired Amount:</label>
<input type="text" id="tops" name="tank" value="0" />
<asking for information about the user, their name etc>
<input type="submit" value="GET ME MY MERCHINDISE ALREADY!"/>
</form>
```

And then using python I retrieve the form information:

```
import cgi 
form=cgi.FieldStorage()
num_tank=int(form.getvalue("tank"))
```

and when I run this it says that that is a none type value so it cannot be converted into a string. So what am I doing wrong here and how do I fix this?

Comment: What does your `<form>` tag look like?

Comment: Is this pure CGI on a plain Apache or nginx server or similar? Can you produce the `os.environ` dictionary (perhaps with `import pprint, os; pprint.pprint(os.environ)`).

Comment: Umm im not too familiar with this to be honest, I just know that im not messing with servers or anything. Its just a simple html webpage

Answer (score 0):

The int() argument must be a string,a bytes-like object or a number.
It looks like the value returned from form.getvalue is Blank.

Remove the int() and try as **num_tank=form.getvalue("tank")**

Have you tried printing the form.getvalue before passing ?
If not, Please verify it might help;

Comment: Perhaps the actual question to be answered here is **why** `form.getvalue()` returns `None`. It is not just blank, it is *missing*.

Comment: why would it be missing though? I'm using the correct name of the input

Comment: @Homam: ah, no, `cgi.FieldStorage` handles either, my mistake.

Comment: Other statements have worked im just not sure as to why this doesnt